# Detecting Horizontal Mouse Wheel movement

Tags: .net, events, mouse, mousewheel

I am using the mousewheel in my DotNet application, which I have done by following: 
[MSDN MouseWheel example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

But on my application it would be great to also use the existing hardware **horizontal** mouse wheel too. But how can I detect when this is used in .Net?

I am using [Logitech RX1500](http://www.logitech.com/de-ch/639/4431) or or [m-RAG97](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/428/783). 
[image]

Regards

-

*** Solution ***

Override the WinProc to catch the mouse wheel event.

```
MustInherit Class Win32Messages
    Public Const WM_MOUSEHWHEEL As Integer = &H20e
    'discovered via Spy++
End Class



Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
    If m.HWnd <> Me.Handle Then
        Return
    End If
    Select Case m.Msg
        Case Win32Messages.WM_MOUSEHWHEEL
            FireMouseHWheel(m.WParam, m.LParam)
            m.Result = DirectCast(1, IntPtr)
            Exit Select
        Case Else
            Exit Select

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the horizontal wheel? what kind of mouse do you have?

Comment: I've added picture and example device.

Comment: Hi Nasenbaer, I see you're still an active SO member, so hopefully you will respond to this. I'm trying to do this in a VB.NET 2010 app. I've converted all the code in the post CodeNaked directed you to. But I've got a problem with the 1st line of the 1st FireMouseWheel sub – `Dim tilt As Int32 = DirectCast(Utils.HIWORD(wParam), Int16)`. It's showing the error `Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'Short'` with `Utils.HIWORD(wParam)` highlighted. I presume you must have overcome this obstacle, so I would appreciate it if you could give me a little guidance on it. Cheers!

Comment: Not to worry, I've sorted it out. I replaced the DirectCast function with CType and it works – although I was also getting an ObjectDisposedException error in WndProc after closing my form so I had to add a line at the top to check the IsDisposed property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [blog post](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2007/07/27/mouse-tilt-wheel-horizontal-scrolling-in-c/) shows how you can add support to a WinForms application.