# How to handle WM_MOUSEHWHEEL the way Explorer does it?

Tags: c#, scroll, mousewheel

I have Logitech M705 mouse with a scroll wheel that allows for horizontal scrolling. I have successfully implemented a handler for this button event in my C# program (implemented as described [here](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2007/07/27/mouse-tilt-wheel-horizontal-scrolling-in-c/)), but so far I can only get it to scroll *once*. In Explorer, when I press the wheel to the right, it scrolls to the right *continuously* until I release the wheel. In my program, it scrolls only one step. The [WM_MOUSEHWHEEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message is not seen until I release and press the wheel again!

**Q:** How do you implement *continuous* horizontal scrolling for the `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL` message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999659/make-mouse-tilt-horizontal-scrolling-always-repeat, the solution is VB.NET but that is easily translated to C#.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much what I have already implemented. The problem is not to handle the message. The problem is that the message is sent only once. This is also true for Explorer.exe so I really don't understand how they manage to get the continuous scrolling. I can't see no extra messages in Spy++...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to all controls (form, children etc):

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    const int WM_MOUSEHWHEEL = 0x020E;
    if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEHWHEEL)
    {
        m.Result = new IntPtr(HIWORD(m.WParam) / WHEEL_DELTA);
    }
}
```

The key is to return a nonzero value for all controls that might process the message!

Answer (score 0):

Use IMessageFilter

```
    public partial class MyForm: Form, IMessageFilter
...
 public ImageForm(Image initialImage)
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        }

/// <summary>
        /// Filters out a message before it is dispatched.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// true to filter the message and stop it from being dispatched; false to allow the message to continue to the next filter or control.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="m">The message to be dispatched. You cannot modify this message. </param><filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
        public bool PreFilterMessage( ref Message m )
        {
            if (m.Msg.IsWindowMessage(WindowsMessages.MOUSEWHEEL))  //if (m.Msg == 0x20a)
            {   // WM_MOUSEWHEEL, find the control at screen position m.LParam      
                var pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16);
                var hWnd = WindowFromPoint(pos);
                if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero && hWnd != m.HWnd && FromHandle(hWnd) != null)
                {
                    SendMessage(hWnd, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point pt);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
```

also in form closing add:

```
Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
```

This will pick up an all windows messages (although only mousewheel is trapped here) - by using the mouseposition to find the control its over, you can then force windows to send the message to that control even if it has no focus.

NOTE: I have used WindowsMessages.MOUSEWHEEL which is from a class I have that enumerates the messages, just replace

> ```
> if (m.Msg.IsWindowMessage(WindowsMessages.MOUSEWHEEL))
> ```

with the commented bit at the end

> `if (m.Msg == 0x20a)`